# Evitar el uso de Firebase desde la consola de Chrome

Tags: javascript, firebase, consola, chrome

Cómo evitar ejecutar métodos de **Firebase** dentro de la consola de Chrome o de algún otro navegador.

Al tener una página web que use **Firebase**, cualquier usuario familiarizado con los métodos de **Firebase**, podría crear / modificar usuarios o grabar datos, etc.

Por ejemplo, si alguien inserta las siguientes líneas en la consola:

```js
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword('polo@kale.com', '1234').catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  console.log(error.code);
  console.log(error.message)
  // ...
});
```

Se creará un usuario de Firebase.
Igual puede ser un *snippet* para crear una referencia en la Base de datos o incluso eliminar toda la base de datos (sobre todo si es un usuario registrado).

¿Hay alguna forma de poder inhabilitar el uso de la consola o inyectar de alguna forma **Firebase** para que no fuera global?

Comment: No creo que se posible evitar que la consola del navegador se comunique con el servidor. Por otro lado, me parece que deberías replantear tu pregunta para hacerla más clara enfocándola al tema de seguridad en particular al de autorización. Además de que el usuario esté registrado debe tener permisos para poder hacer algo como borrar la base de datos.

Comment: OK, lo pongo más fácil. Me dedico a hacer apps con dinámicas e interacción con redes sociales, para juegos fundamentados en acciones de marketing... son juegos para captar más seguidores y los premios van de viajes a otro país hasta cenas en restaurantes locales... mi experiencia me demostrado que siempre hay gente que intenta hackear este tipo de plataformas, sea cual sea el lenguaje.

Comment: Con Firebase (si estás familiarizado) con que seas un usuario registrado puedes crear más usuarios y grabar registros en la BD. ¿qué datos puedes grabar o borrar? ciertamente depende de los permisos que otorgues, pero de que se puede, se puede. La idea es evitar que se pueda a través de la consola. ¿Algún consejo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No puedes limitar la funcionalidad de crear una cuenta, puedes deshabilitar proveedores( email, twitter, facebook, etc) . Pero la capacidad de registrar una cuenta debe mantenerse pública (a menos que los agregues tu manualmente por la consola).

Esto no quiere decir que la base de datos esta accesible y editable para cualquiera. Firebase cuenta con [reglas de seguridad](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) que se pueden definir en la consola de Firebase y que pueden limitar la escritura e incluso la lectura de cualquier nodo de la base. Con estas reglas puedes por ejemplo limitar:

- Que sólo usuarios en una lista de administradores puedan ver o editar determinados nodos.
- Que un usuario solo puede ver y escribir datos dentro de SU nodo.
- Que un usuario requiera una cuenta ya validada para cargar datos.
- limitar los archivos que pueden subir/ver esos usuarios a Firebase Storage.

Espero que te sirva.